# Java TFS SDK - How to get changes made in a Specfic commit

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm able to get list of Build Definitions in a Project. Then obtained the Builds under each Build Definition and commit details under each Build. Right now I'm only getting 6 fields in Commit details.

```
Author
CommitId
Committer
Message
Timestamp
Uri
```

But I don't able to find any api to obtain the changes made in that commit. I want do some string parsing in the commit changes to obtain a value. Is it possible to get commit changes by respective commit using TFS SDK..?

Comment: Do commit details mean Build details? Or do you mean Associated changes under the Builds? Usually, there are Definition, Source version, Requested by, and time of Queued, Started, Finished in Build Details, there is no changes in it.

Comment: What the version of TFS do you use? TFS 2015?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT , TFS 2013

Answer (score 1):

TFS SDK for Java does not provide a full feature to interact with Git repositories. There is a Rest API which can [get this information](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#with-changed-items) easily but it is only supported from TFS 2015. Since you are using TFS 2013, the alternative way would be use [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#language-bindings) to get the detailed information about a commit.

Comment: Actually I need to get the RCS folder name of every commit (i.e., Folder under which the files were changed). Is it possible by Java SDK?

Comment: @TheCoder I'm afraid that the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to get the associated changeset summaries from the specified build. Then you are looking for [InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets Method (IBuildDetail)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339559(v=vs.120).aspx).

Check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797568/how-to-retrieve-changesets-associated-with-a-build-in-tfs-2013-with-git) which should help you:

"

After a lot of fiddling around I finally found the solution. Changeset's have been renamed to Commit's for TFS 2013's git support. Consequently you need to ask for that data when you get build details like this:

```
var buildDetailSpec = _buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(buildDefinitionUris);
buildDetailSpec.InformationTypes = new[] { "AssociatedCommit" };
```

Then you perform the query as usual:

```
var buildQueryResult = _buildServer.QueryBuilds(new [] { buildDetailSpec });
var buildDetail = buildQueryResult[0].Builds;
```

Then you retrieve the commit, not the changeset, like this:

```
var commits = buildDetail.Information.GetNodesByType("AssociatedCommit");
var author = commits.First().Fields["Author"];
var comments = commits.First().Fields["Message"];
```

"

Comment: Yes, I've get AssociatedCommit made under a build which might contain one or more commits. I've already obtained the 6 fields under every commit. But it doesn't include changes (maybe called Changeset?) made in a commit (like file add/update/delete performed in that commit).