# How to get full history of changes made by an user/account on any project

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to know if is it possible to get a full history of changes made by my personal account (@outlook.com) on any account/project in Visual Studio Team Services that I have ever worked on (even if one or many of those projects actually exists or not).

I do not need the full change set info, just the project name, check-in date, and maybe the numbers/names of files affected.

Comment: Just source control, or other things as well (work items, builds, etc)?

Comment: @DanielMann just source control check-in's, I need a list of all the check-ins I made since I joined to VSO (in any VSO Account and also any project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from Source Control Explorer\Find Changesets.
[image]

And you can also specify the project on "Containing file" text-box if you want.

Or use VSTS Rest API: [GetlistofchangesetsByperson](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#GetlistofchangesetsByperson)

Comment: I think you did not get my point here, I want to get the full history of check in in any accounts/projects I have ever participated, the way you show only works if my personal account is currently associated to the account/project, but there are many project I already finished my work so I have no access. The same applies for the REST API, I must be member of the account where the projects are located.

Comment: @JorgeRamírez Sorry for the misunderstand. There isn't any way to achieve the feature you want for now. Just as you said, you have no access to the account/project, then you cannot search the information from those account/projects. The only way to do this is ask the person who has the access to them to get these information.

Comment: So, there are no logs in my account that let me know at least some basic info about all the check-ins I made? I do not need a lot of info just some basic fields (project name, check in date)

Comment: @JorgeRamírez No, these information are all stored in the changesets and not relate to your account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you will have to work for it.

You can get a list of VSTS accounts that you have permission for from your profile on VisualStudio.com. Not sure if there is an api for  this list, but it is there.

Note: You will not see, nor be able to access, any Account or Team Project that you no longer have permission for.

Now that you have a list of  accounts you can  use the VSTS API to iterate through each of the accounts  and each of  the Team Projects to get your history.

You will need to determin, for each team project, if it is Git or TFVC and iterate accordingly.

[How to get the History of the sourcecontrol in TFS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493835/how-to-get-the-history-of-the-sourcecontrol-in-tfs-api)